# Highstock Shared Tooltip This Index

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have to use the shared formatted tooltip, how do I get the index of the point I am hovering on? I've tried other proposed solutions on stack-overflow and none work.

```
tooltip: {useHTML: true, shared: true, formatter: function (tooltip) {

// where the hell is it!

var nodes = this.points;}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by index of the point?

Comment: this.points[ accessedindex ] where accessedindex is the point being accessed

Answer (score 1):

In a formatter callback with a shared tooltip you will not be able to distinguish which point has been hovered so you cannot get the point's index directly. However, the point which is looked for is stored as chart.hoverPoint.

```
formatter: function(tooltip) {

    // where the hell is it!
    var nodes = this.points,
            current = nodes[0].series.chart.hoverPoint;
    console.log(current, current.series.name);
    return current.series.name;
  }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/g7gkuf4s/3/